# AJAX POST request to a PHP server: Invalid request (Malformed HTTP request) on console and net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE on chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I have the files `test.html`, `test.js` and `test.php` in my directory. I am trying to send some data to my backend, which should be dealt with by `test.php`. I run my server using PHP's built-in webserver with the command `php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t test-server/`.

Here's a simplified demonstration, whenever I click "submit", it should send the data to my php server. The JS:

```js
window.onload = () => {
    submit = document.getElementById('submit');
    submit.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onload = function() {
            window.location.replace("test.php");
        }
        xhttp.open("test.php", "POST", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        var data = {'name':'foo'};
        xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
}
```

And here's my PHP:

```php
<?php 
    echo "foo";
    var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

However, the data isn't being sent, and the `xhttp.onload` never works. The error `Invalid request (Malformed HTTP request)` shows up on my server and the error `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` pops up in chrome's developer tools.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xhttp.open uses this signature:

```
open(method, url, async, user, password)
```

You just inversed method and url in your call.

More informations: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open

Comment: My bad, I swear I saw that the url comes before method till I revisited the site again. False memories